# Windows - file opened by another process, still can rename it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, psutil

On **Windows** OS, just before doing some actions on my file, I need to know if it's in use by another process. After some serious research over all the other questions with a similar problem, I wasn't able to find a working solution for it.

`os.rename(my_file.csv, my_file.csv)` is still working even if I have the file opened with ... notepad let's say.

`psutil` ... it took too much time and it doesn't work (can't find my file path in `nt.path`:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        flist = proc.open_files()
        if flist:
            for nt in flist:
                if my_file_path == nt.path:
                   print("it's here")
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess as err:
      print(err)
```

Is there any other solution for this?

**UPDATE 1**

I have to do 2 actions on this file: 1. check if the filename corresponds to a pattern; 2. copy it over SFTP.

**UPDATE 2 + solution**

Thanks to @Eryk Sun, I found out that Notepad "reads the contents into memory and then closes the handle". After opening my file with Word, `os.rename` and `psutil` are working like a (py)charm.

Comment: Notepad reads the contents into memory and then closes the handle. If it saves the updated file to the original filename instead of a new name, it simply overwrites the original file. There is no way for another program to know that an instance of Notepad will write to a particular filename.

Comment: Then, it makes sense why I'm not getting the expected response from `os.rename`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Anyway, `os.rename` can succeed if a file is already open. A rename requires delete access, which is allowed if all open references to the file only have metadata access (e.g. attributes, extended attributes, security) and no data access (i.e. read/execute, write/append, or delete) or if all open references that have data access also share delete access (i.e. `CreateFileW` is called with at least `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`).

Comment: Well, the only access that my file could have is data access, so in my case, I don't have to worry about it. ^_^

Comment: No, if the file is opened with delete-access sharing (`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`), then `os.rename` will succeed. The C standard library and Python's standard library only open temporary, delete-on-close files with delete-access sharing, but in general Windows programs open files with `CreateFileW` and can easily share delete access. That it's uncommon doesn't mean checking `os.rename` is a reliable way to determine whether other programs have the file open with data access.

Comment: The way to check is with a `CreateFileW` call that requests `FILE_READ_DATA` access and 0 sharing. If a previous open has read/execute, write/append, or delete access, the call will fail with a sharing violation (32).

Answer (score 0):

If the program You use opens the file by **importing** it (like Excel would do it, for example), that means that it transforms Your data in a readable form for itself, without keeping a hand on the actual file afterwards. If You save the file from there, it either saves it in the programs own format or exports (and transforms) the file back.

What dou You want to do with the file? Maybe You can simply copy the file?

Comment: First thing - check if the filename corresponds to a pattern. Second - copy over SFTP to a server. Maybe it's a big file still in use so i have to make sure of that...